# Smart-Capture / Salesforce integration in ExactTarget Developer Org

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforce1-app

I am working with a developer Org (**ExactTarget**). There are 2 features that are missing from the Org -

1. I don't get Smart Capture Orientation option when I create a content in ExactTarget.
2. I don't get the Integrate button on ExactTarget User screen to set ExactTarget users with Salesforce.com Status.

How can these features be activated in the account? We are developing demonstrations for our customer on integration between Salesforce.com / ExactTarget.

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Gaurav.

I logged a support case got enabled the Smart Capture rule as well as the Salesforce.com Integration rule in my account.

This has enabled the Smart Capture and Integration features.

Regards,
Vineet

Answer (score 4):

For 1), refer [this](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/) link - You must have either the landing pages or the microsites feature enabled on your account to use Smart Capture. If you have one of these enabled and you still don't see Smart Capture Orientation, I would recommend using a support case.

For 2), make sure you have met all the stated pre-requisites on this link.

> 1. Set up one of the following Salesforce.com editions: Unlimited, Enterprise, or Performance. Person Accounts are supported. Please
>      note: Professional Edition is not supported in v5. Professional
>      Edition is supported in v2.
> 2. Set up one of the following Agency or Agency Client Editions: Core Edition, Advanced Edition, Enterprise Edition, Enterprise 2.0 Edition,
>      or Reseller Edition.  Please note: On-Your-Behalf (OYB) accounts are
>      not supported.
> 3. Set up Business Rules in ExactTarget. For this step, please contact your ExactTarget Account Executive to enable Salesforce integration
>      for your ExactTarget account.  Note: To ensure the integrity of
>      customer data, only new customers can install v5. A new customer is a
>      customer who has never installed a Salesforce Integration package.
> 4. Obtain administrator credentials/permissions for logging in to Salesforce.com and ExactTarget.com
> 5. Ensure four (4) custom tabs are available in Salesforce.
> 6. Compile a list of integration users.
> 7. Create a report that defines an intended Send To list. For example, create a report that returnsonly your own contact record.
> 8. Create a test email.
> 9. Install the most recent version of the Chrome or Firefox browsers.
> 10. Subscriber Key is required for the v5 integration. If it is not active in your account you will need to go through a Subscriber Key
>       Migration before proceeding with the v5 integration process. For more
>       information about Subscriber Key, please click here.
> 11. Ensure that all Default Sender Profiles, Delivery Profiles and Send Classifications have not been deleted or renamed.